# I need to create a back button functionality in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I am presently using something like this binding this code to fxml javafx button

```
Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("AolRun.fxml"));
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
stage = (Stage) run.getScene().getWindow();
Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
stage.setScene(scene);
scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/Style.css");
stage.setTitle("Output");
stage.setResizable(false);
stage.show();
```

Is there a generic function we can use for back which just transits screen from the present fxml scene to the next fxml .

I have separate scene for every fxml.

Comment: It is better to use one Scene and just change the parent layout of the Scene.

Comment: I already have my application already built is there any option

Answer (score 1):

1)A better approach is to change the parent layout and use only one Scene.

2)Although you can have the functionality you want using a `Button`.When the `onAction` method is fired you choose in what `Scene` to go.You can either have the Scenes stored in the array and move to the next or previous index, or implement your own logic which `Scene` will follow or which Scene is the previous of the current Scene.

Here is where the 1 is more usefull cause you can go to the next or previous "Scene" using an Animation.For example `TransitionAnimation`.

> ~~> In addition to the comments below

If you want to know in which Scene was the user before you can use an ObservableList or Array.

Everytime the user changes Scene ,the previous Scene is stored in the array.

Comment: But the issue here is how do i know which is the previous scene or the previous fxml file , shall i hardcode it

Comment: @Rahul Singh You want to know which was the previous Scene that the user was?Explain a little bit the logic of the app.

Comment: Yes the app is actually like the user will have options to search different values related to different options and after he has searched all the results of a option if he wants to move to a different option he has to go back to the option screen right. So i know from which screen he is coming but instead of maintaining a variable can i get it from javafx directly.

Comment: @Rahul Singh As far as i know you have to implement it... not so hard. :)