# How to go back to previous page with back button and different controllers? JAVAFX, JAVA

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am fairly new to JAVAFX so please bear with me. Any help is greatly appreciated. Firstly, i have a Main app that loads addItems.fxml and addItemsController.

```
public class UncookedApp extends Application {

private Stage stage;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    stage = primaryStage;

    try {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/uncooked/view/addItems.fxml"));
        AnchorPane root=loader.load();
        addItemsController itemsCtrl=loader.getController();
        itemsCtrl.setMainApp(this);
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,1024,768);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Stage getStage() {
    return stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

This is part of the addItemsController:

```
private UncookedApp mainApp;

public UncookedApp getMainApp() {
    return mainApp;
}
public void setMainApp(UncookedApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;
}
public void toMeat(ActionEvent event) {
    Stage stage1=mainApp.getStage();
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
          loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/uncooked/view/addMeat.fxml"));
        Parent root=loader.load();
        addMeatCtrl itemsCtrl=loader.getController();
    //  itemsCtrl.setMainApp(this);
        Scene scene=new Scene(root,1024,768);
        stage1.setScene(scene);
        stage1.show();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The addItemsController will load a different page, addMeat. I got that to work but when I try to go back from addMeat to addItems with a button handle, it doesn't work. Is it something to do with retrieving the mainApp's stage? How can I solve this?

This is what I've tried.

```
public void handleBackFromMeat(ActionEvent event) {
try{
    Stage stage=mainApp.getStage();
    FXMLLoader loader=new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/uncooked/view/addItems.fxml"));
    Parent root=loader.load();
    addItemsController itemsCtrl=loader.getController();
    Scene scene=new Scene(root,1024,768);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}


}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you switch to the 'addMeat'  page? Also could you please post the part where you try to go back to thebprevious page? The code you posted right now has nothing to do with the  parts I mentioned above.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens? You can have a look at [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/acaicedo/entry/managing_multiple_screens_in_javafx1) which shows a reasonable approach to this (it is much better than  storing global data in `public static` lists).

Answer (score 1):

I also had posted a similar question and then i went ahead with my way

[I need to create a back button functionality in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484234/i-need-to-create-a-back-button-functionality-in-javafx)

What you can do as i did for my application was make two static list at the start of the application and then fill it with the Stage and the Fxml page name if you are using fxml and then have a central back button method on each page to move the previous page by iterating on the last item added to the list .

Two static lists in the main class

```
public static List<Stage>stageval = new ArrayList<Stage>();
public static List<String>fxmlval = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When ever i switch my fxml view i added the stage and the fxml file name to their respective lists.

```
fxmlval.add("Instance.fxml");                                   
stage = (Stage)validate.getScene().getWindow();
stageval.add((Stage) delete.getScene().getWindow());
```

And a central back button method when ever the user clicked the back button i iterated to last item of both the lists and then after changing the stage deleted the values from the list .

```
public class BackButton {

    public void back(String instance,Stage stage) throws IOException{
                    Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(instance));
                    Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
                    scene.getStylesheets().add("/css/Style.css");
                    stage.setResizable(false);
                    stage.setScene(scene);
                    stage.show();
    }
}

@FXML
public void back() throws IOException {
    BackButton bb = new BackButton();

    bb.back(fxmlval.get(fxmlval.size() - 1),        
    stageval.get(stageval.size() - 1));
    fxmlval.remove(fxmlval.size() - 1);
    stageval.remove(stageval.size() - 1);
}
```

Hope this helps its a work around but the solution works.